# MainActivity is not an enclosing class in Fragment Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, main-activity

I have two Android Studio projects opened. One is the actual app, other is a testing project. In the testing project I have used this code in MainActivity.java and it worked perfectly. Now when I try to transfer it to my actual app project, it doesn't work. Probably because the code is inside a fragment class and not MainActivity.

This is the code I'm talking about:

```
private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
        try {
            Transport.send(messages[0]);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What it does is simply display the message "Sending email" while it does so on the screen. I'm not sure if I should copy the whole class if needed, so tell me if it is so.

The error is shown at this line:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
```

It says: 'com.example.private.privateprivate.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class'.

I'm unsure what to do since if I put MainFragment.this, it gives an error and says: 'Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.example.private.privateprivate.MainFragment', required: 'android.content.Context'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` as the first argument.

You need a `Context` object in order to call `show()`. When your AsyncTask was living inside of an activity, the way to get one was to reference the encosing activity directly using `MainActivity.this`. Now that your task is living inside of a Fragment, you can't do that. But fragments have a `getActivity()` method that will return their activity, so you can use that instead.